# RegistryKey.GetValue(..) returns null

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a (REG_SZ) registry key and write it to a string. However this code seems to think the key is null or doesn't exist and won't allow me to `GetValue()` it. Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the value.

```
string s64BasePath = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Xactware\\";
private void versionSelectorBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showForms();
    sVersionSelected = versionServerBox.Text;
    if (b64Bit == true)
    {
        string sRKey = s64BasePath + sVersionSelected + "\\"; //Reads as SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Xactware\\Xactimate28\\
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sRKey))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                //label1.Text = "Test."; //Reaches this point just fine
                Object o = key.GetValue("Location");
                if (o != null)
                {
                    //label1.Text = "Test."; //Does not reach this point, o = null?
                    sLocationKey = Convert.ToString(o);
                }
            }
        }
        //label1.Text = sLocationKey;
}
```

Here is what the registry looks like. As you can see the Location key exists in the path provided. However the code isn't dropping into the inner most if statement, acting like the `o` object is null.

[image: Registry Key Screenshot]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "//Reads as SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Xactware\\Xactimate28\\" is an incorrect comment. That is *not* the key being opened. Is this a typo or is it really a different key being accessed? Also, don't supply a trailing "\\" to OpenSubKey. If you *attach a debugger* you can inspect the `key` object directly - use the Watch or Immediate Evaluation Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be honest, without having Xactimate installed, I do not have the same registry entry you do so I used Skype as my key.

[image]

I changed one thing, I changed it from \ to using the literal string flag.
FYI, I ran in this in LINQPad so ignore the 'dump' commands

```
var test = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Skype\Phone";
var reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(test);
reg.Dump("OpenSubKey: ");
var result = reg.GetValue("SkypeFolder");
result.Dump("GetValue: ");
```

Here are the results from the two dumps
[image]

Comment: I figured out what my issue was, `sVersionSelected = versionServerBox.Text;` was pulling from the wrong text box and I didn't realize it. It's meant to get from `versionSelectorBox` but I got it working thanks to you giving me some code to troubleshoot mine against. Thanks!